# ReportBuilder calculated field always shows #Error on the report

Tags: ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I am trying to put add a calculated field to my report in ReportBuilder. The most basic calculated field throws `#Error` when placed on my report. An expression as simple as the one below throws an `#Error` when placed on a report.

```
MyCalcField = "Hello"
```

I am using the following steps to create the calculated field.

1. In the Report Data pane, right-click the dataset, and then click Add Calculated Field.

[image]

2. In the Fields page of the Dataset Properties dialog box, click Add, and then click Calculated Field. A new row is added to the bottom of the grid.
3. In the Field Source text box, type the expression for the field. Click the expression *(fx*) button to build an expression.

[image]

[image]

4. Select OK.
5. Add the newly created field to the report.
6. When I run the report, the calculated field (regardless of the expression) shows `#Error`.

[image]

### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong? Can calculated fields be shown on a report?
2. It does not matter what the calculation is. They all show `#Error` when placed on the report.
3. Is it possible to use a third-party Report Builder in SSRS?